# $q: default reject handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I want to return a $q instance so that if clients don't call 'then' with a reject handler, then a default one runs.

E.g. assume the default is to `alert(1)`

Then `mypromise.then(function(result){...})` will alert 1 but `mypromise.then(null, function(reason){alert(2)})` will alert 2

Comment: Don't think that the promises syntax scope, second parameter expects to be failure callback

Comment: `$q.finally` can be used, but you can't branch with it.

Comment: One way would be to use a promise library like bluebird which has this functionality built in (onPossiblyUnhandledRejection) - that said the use case sounds really strange - care to elaborate?

Comment: The use case is that if the error is not handled I want to display a message. In essence I want something similar to a catch all in a main loop that you see in other architectures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Let's assume there was a way to do that.

So we have a magical machine that can always find out if `.then` is called with a function second argument for a specific promise or not.

#### So what?

So you can detect if someone did:

```
myPromise.then(..., function(){ F(); });
```

At any point from anywhere at any time. And have `G()` as a default action.

#### And...?

You could take a whole program containing lots of code P <sub>(1)</sub> and convert that code to:

```
var myPromise = $q.reject();
P; // inline the program's code
myPromise.then(null, function(){}); // attach a handler
```

#### Great, so I can do that, so?

Well, now our magical machine can take an arbitrary program P and detect if `myPromise` had a rejection handler added to it. Now this happens if and only if `P` does not contain an infinite loop (i.e. it halts). Thus, our method of detecting if a catch handler is ever added is [reduced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction) to [the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Which is [impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem). <sub>(2)</sub>

So generally - it is impossible to detect if a `.catch` handler is ever attached to a promise.

### Stop with the mumbu-jumbo, I want a solution!

Good response! Like many problems this one is *theoretically* impossible but in practice easy enough to solve for practical cases. The key here is a heuristic:

> If an error handler is not attached within a microtask (digest in Angular) - no error handlers are ever attached and we can fire the default handler instead.

That is roughly: You *never* `.then(null, function(){})` asynchronously. Promises are resolved asynchronously but the handlers are usually attached synchronously so this works nicely.

```
// keeping as library agnostic as possible.
var p = myPromiseSource(); // get a promise from source
var then = p.then; // in 1.3+ you can get the constructor and use prototype instead
var t = setTimeout(function(){ // in angular use $timeout, not a microtask but ok
    defaultActionCall(p);// perform the default action!
});
// .catch delegates to `.then` in virtually every library I read so just `then`
p.then = function then(onFulfilled, onRejected){
    // delegate, I omitted progression since no one should use it ever anyway.
    if(typeof onRejected === "function"){ // remove default action
        clearTimeout(t); // `timeout.cancel(t)` in Angular     
    }
    return then.call(this, onFulfilled, onRejected);
};
```

### Is that all?

Well, I just want to add that cases where this extreme approach is needed are rare. When discussing adding rejection tracking to io - several people suggested that if a promise is rejected without a `catch` then the whole app should likely terminate. So take extra care :)

<sup>(1) assume P does not contain a variable myPromise, if it does rename myPromise to something P does not contain.</sup>

<sup>(2) Of course - one can say that it is enough to read the code of P and not run it in order to detect `myPromise` gets a rejection handler. Formally we say that we change every `return` in P and other forms of termination to a `return myPromise.then(null, function(){})` instead of simply putting it in the end. this way the "conditionality" is captured.</sup>

Comment: Even if you need to attach asynchronously you can always add `promise.catch(function(){})` synchronously as it only creates a new fork that is guaranteed to be fulfilled always.

Comment: What if I have two promises chain? One next to the other. The first has a handler. The second doesn't. When resolving, the first succeeds, but not the second. Since all "thens" are executed synchronously, the default action  won't be triggered.